# Mod_Rewrite with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to turn this "index.php?page=Home" into this "index/Home" or just "Home".
I tried reading this "http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/" but still cant figure out how to do it. Any help?

this is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^index/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$   index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "index"
```

Comment: Please post the code that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a "?" at the end of your variable ([A-Za-z0-9-]+)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^index/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$   index.php?page=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "index"
```

Comment: are you typing "index/Home" in your browser?

Comment: No. but when I do it removes the styles sheets

Comment: But that's the goal, that you should type "http://your-website-here/index/Home" and it will route to "http://your-website-here/index.php?page=Home

Comment: When I type that it removes all my stylesheets

Comment: So you get to the correct page, but it's just your style sheets that stop working? What is the link for one of your style sheets (what does the link tag say: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp ?